# create a site column with preferred display name in CSOM

Tags: 2013, csom

I want to create a site column with preferred display name and internal name under a particular group.

I gone through these sites

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/site-column-in-sharepoint-2010-programmatically-using-vs-201/

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/08/how-to-add-site-column-programmatically.html

Is there a way to achieve what i want using CSOM?

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code sample:

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteURL");
 FieldCollection fieldCollection = context.Web.Fields;
 fieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml(@"<Field ID='{4AA6616E-E435-4B52-A30B-54B7D3EE6260}' Type='Text'
                                            Name='InternalName'
                                            Required='TRUE'
                                            DisplayName='DisplayName'
                                            Description=''
                                            Group='GroupName'/>",true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `CSOM` with `PowerShell` to create Site Columns, then refer following code.

**Connect to SharePoint Site, and load all Site Columns**

```
$url ="http://YourSite"
# site columns
$Name ="YourSiteColumnInternalName"
Write-Host "authenticate to SharePoint site collection $url and get ClientContext object" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = Get-Credential 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$web = $context.Web
$fields = $web.Fields;         
$site = $context.Site 
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($fields)
$context.Load($site)
try
{
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "authenticateed to SharePoint site collection $url and get ClientContext object succeefully" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Not able to authenticateed to SharePoint site collection $url $_.Exception.Message" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
    return
}
```

**Check if Site Column already exists in collection**

```
Write-Host "Check if the site column" $Name "is exist or not" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
foreach ($item in $fields)
{
    if ($item.InternalName -eq $Name)
    {
        Write-Host "Site column" $Name "is already exist" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
        return
    }
}
```

**If your site column do not exists, then add it in the Site Column collections**

```
Write-Host "creating site column" $Name -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow 

$fieldAsXML = 
            "<Field Type='Text' 
            DisplayName='Your Display Name'
            Name='"+$Name+"'
            ID='{545E5A0D-5553-4E02-97B3-F2D225B649D7}'
            Group='Your Site Columns' />";

$fieldOption = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::DefaultValue

$field = $fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldAsXML, $true, $fieldOption)
$context.Load($field)
try
{
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Site column" $Name "created successfully" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green 
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error while creating site column" $Name $_.Exception.Message -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red 
    return
}
```